# Парсинг данных через GET запрос Elasticsearch

Tags: java, http, парсер, get, elasticsearch

Не понятно как сформировать запрос к базе Elasticsearch. на официальном сайте пример запроса

```
GET /bank/_search
{
  "query": { "match_all": {} }
}
```

Непонятен синтаксис запроса, то есть информация в фигурных скобках(формирующая критерии запроса, необходимые поля, значения) каким образом её отправлять через GET запрос и возможно ли вообще полученные JSON-поля распарсить в JAVA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Синтаксис запросов описан в разделах документации [Request Body Search](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-body.html) и [Query DSL](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html).

Если вас смущает именно наличие тела у GET-запроса, это не запрещено  протоколом HTTP.

Для отправки запроса у вас есть в принципе два основных варианта:

1. Формировать JSON-строку вручную либо с использованием одной из бибилиотек для работы с JSON ([Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson), [google-gson](https://github.com/google/gson)) и отправлять GET-запрос любым HTTP клиентом: стандартным [`java.net.URLConnection`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html) либо чем-то сторонним ([Apache HttpComponents](https://hc.apache.org/), [Async Http Client](https://github.com/AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client)). После чего все той же JSON-библиотекой разбирать ответ.
2. Воспользоваться готовым Java-клиентом к API, предоставляющим удобные обертки. С его использованием выполнение запроса из вашего примера будет выглядеть так:

   ```
   SearchResponse response = client.prepareSearch(QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery())
                                   .setQuery()
                                   .get();
   ```

   В таком варианте вам совсем не придется иметь дела с JSON и HTTP.

Comment: спасибо, начал разбираться с этой библиотекой. может быть вы подскажите как правильно составить запрос http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/642931/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%BA-elasticsearch-%D0%B8%D0%B7-java-api#642931
я пытаюсь посчитать количество документов по каждому параметру. понял что надо использовать term для агрегации, а вот как во втором поле искать не конкретное значение а посчитать для конкретного не понимаю.