# Запрос к Elasticsearch из Java-клиента

Tags: java, elasticsearch

```
"aggs": {
    "2": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "dns.question.type",
        "size": 1000,
        "order": {
          "_count": "desc"
        }
```

Не понимаю как добавить агрегацию к запросу Java API elasticsearch. Необходимо посчитать количество документов по каждому типу значений dns.question.type и вернуть их. то есть два поля:первое dns.question.type, второе количество документов этого типа.Пытаюсь вначале с помощью функции terms определить количество уникальных значений "dns.question.type" ,необходимо еще получить второе поле которое подсчитывает количество записей каждого типа "dns.question.type" :

```
    SearchResponse response = client.prepareSearch("packetbeat")
   .setQuery(QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("@timestamp").gte("now-12d").lt("now-10d"))
   .addAggregation(AggregationBuilders.terms("")
```

И как мне после изъять значения из response например в хэш мап.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сам разобрался:

```
SearchResponse response = client.prepareSearch("packetbeat-2017.03.12")                           .setQuery(QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("@timestamp").gte("now-12d").lt("now-10d"))
               .addAggregation(AggregationBuilders
               .terms("type").field("dns.question.type").size(5))
               .execute().actionGet();
Map<String, Object> res=new HashMap<String, Object>();
Terms dns_question_types=response.getAggregations().get("type");
for (Terms.Bucket entry : dns_question_types.getBuckets()) {
        res.put(entry.getKeyAsString(),entry.getDocCount());
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Для первого результата

```
SearchHit[] hits = response.getHits().getHits();
Map<String, Object> result = hits[0].sourceAsMap();
```